# AWS S3 getting Not a valid bitmap file

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-s3, blob, cordova-plugins

I have been struggling with this for a while and I am going to provide you with as much information as possible (some maybe irrelevant) because I am completely stuck.  I am using Ionic and I would like to be able to take a picture with my phone and upload it to an AWS S3 bucket.  I used [Cordova camera](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html) to accomplish this.

As far as I know; these pictures come out in a large base64 string and I have to convert it to a Blob, convert it to a File object then upload that file object into AWS.  However, when I do this it always uploads it as something other than an image.  Whenever I open it I get an error saying:

```
"Not a valid bitmap file.  its format is not currently supported."
```

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mng-moment/moment/PA/40.008446_-75.26046_1502414224619.jpg

Here is an example of a WORKING one (This used to work it somehow broke):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mng-moment/bestMoments/40.008446_-75.26046_1499659199473.jpg

I tried to open each one in a text editor to see what is going on.  For the first one (The broken one) I get this:

[image]

When I try to open the working one in a text editor I get this:

[image]

Now it seems like a conversion problem but I think I am converting it correctly. 
 Here is the code I am using to upload (You can see the console.logs later on the post):

[image]

core.js

[image]

awsServices.js

[image]

If you look at the comments in the code I labeled some of the console logs.  I will display them here for more information:

A - (uploadToAWS):

[image: A (uploadToAWS)]

B - (awsServices.upload):

[image: B (awsServices.upload)]

This is how I convert the dataURI to a Blob (Called in uplpoadToAWS - The first screenshot):

[image]

This is what gets passed into the 'dataURI' parameter in the code right above:
[image]

If there is any more information please let me know.  I've been scratching my head at this for a while.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [MDN File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File):

> A File object is a specific kind of a Blob, and can be used in any context that a Blob can. In particular, FileReader, URL.createObjectURL(), createImageBitmap(), and XMLHttpRequest.send() accept both Blobs and Files.

So, i think your problem reside in your **uploadToAws** function because you first create a Blob and then use the Blob to create a File, when I think you simply should initialize the File object with the byte array returned by **dataURItoBlob** since the File object is in fact already a Blob object.

Comment: Yes!  I got it to finally work.  I didn't realize a File and Blob were the same thing so I just gave AWS my blob instead of my file and it worked!  I've been stuck on this for almost 2 weeks.  Thanks for that.